# Reporting Services report runs slow on one server and fast on another

Tags: reporting-services

I have an odd problem.  I have an identical code base and report on two different servers.  Server A runs the report in 2 seconds.  Server B runs the report in 15 seconds.

When running SQL Profiler, the duration of each stored procedure is the same.  However, the end times of the procs are different.  Server B seems to have something else going on between the procedures because the end times of the proc are so much longer.

I have no idea where to even begin looking into this issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify "end time" and "run time"? You say the SP take the same time to execute, but have a different "end time"?

Comment: Yes. Let's say I have 3 procs in my report. Looking at it in SQL Profiler, each takes 1 second to run. On Server A, the last proc is done after 4 seconds after the first one started. (looking at the "end time" property. I assume this is from SSRS overhead). Each individual proc duration is 1 second. On Server B, the last proc is done 20 seconds after the first proc started. On this server, each individual proc duration is also 1 second. It seems that the SSRS overhead if much longer on server B. I have no idea what is causing this.